# How to change and manipulate clock in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to manipulate my clock by using my own clock divider module.

```
module clockDivider(input logic input0,
                    input logic input1,
                    input logic clock,
                    output logic y);

// 00 = stop, 01 = slow, 10 = medium, 11 = fast;

if( ~input1 & ~input0 )      /*stop clock*/ ;
else if( ~input1 & input0 )  /*slow*/ ;
else if( input1  & ~input0 ) /*medium*/ ;
else if( input1  & input0 )  /*fast*/ ; 

endmodule
```

As you can see above, according to my inputs, I will manipulate my clock and then let the step motor which is located in our FPGA board. But I couldn't figure out how to do it.

And also is there any website other than [doulos](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/)? I think it is not really clear and contains just a small amount of information about System Verilog.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can directly having a modulo N counter to divide frequency by N.

Suppose here is your all 3 types of clock.

```
00 - No Clock
01 - Clock/4
02 - Clock/2
03 - Clock
```

Here is the code for it. Please note that its a conceptual code and not verified.

```
module clockDivider(input logic input0,
                    input logic input1,
                    input logic clock,
                    input logic reset,
                    output logic y);

// 00 = stop, 01 = slow, 10 = medium, 11 = fast;
parameter mod = 2;
reg [mod-1:0] count, max;

assign y = ( ~input1 & ~input0 ) ? 1'b0 : count[mod-1]; /*stop clock*/

always @ (posedge clock)
begin
if( ~input1 & input0 )  /*slow*/ 
  max <= (1 << (mod-2)) - 1'b1; 
else if( input1  & ~input0 ) /*medium*/ 
  max <= (1 << (mod-1)) - 1'b1; 
else if( input1  & input0 )  /*fast*/  
  max <= (1 << mod) - 1'b1; 
end 

always @ (posedge clock, negedge reset)
begin
  if (!reset)
    count <= 0;
  else if (count == max)
    count <= 0;
  else
    count <= count + 1'b1;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

By `slow`, `medium` and `fast`, I am going to assume that the fastest you are expecting by this logic is the speed of `clock` itself i.e you are implementing a clock divider.

I have assumed the following:

`slow` = 0.25*clock

`medium` = 0.5*clock

`fast` = clock

```
module clockDivider(input logic reset,
                    input logic input0,
                    input logic input1,
                    input logic clock,
                    output logic y);

// 00 = stop, 01 = slow, 10 = medium, 11 = fast;
  logic delayed_y;
  logic delayed_delayed_y;
  logic [1:0] counter;

  always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (reset) begin
      counter <= 'h0;
    end
    else begin
      counter <= counter+1'b1;
    end
  end

  always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (reset) begin
      delayed_y <= 1'b0;
    end
    else begin
      delayed_y <= counter[0];
    end
  end

  always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (reset) begin
      delayed_delayed_y <= 1'b0;
    end
    else begin
      delayed_delayed_y <= counter[1];
    end
  end

  always @(*) begin
    if (reset) begin
      y = 1'b0;
    end
    else begin
      /*stop clock*/
      if( ~input1 & ~input0 ) begin
        y = 1'b0;
      end

      /*slow*/
      else if( ~input1 & input0 ) begin
        y = delayed_delayed_y;
      end

      /* medium*/
      else if( input1  & ~input0 ) begin
        y = delayed_y;
      end

      /* fast */
      else if( input1  & input0 ) begin
        y = clock;
      end
    end
  end

endmodule
```

You can find a working example here: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5J75

**Note:** If you are looking to multiply the clock, you need to use the DCM on your target FPGA. There is another method as well with a 2-input XOR gate and a clock buffer but I would stick to the DCM.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your interest. I am asking this question for beeing sure actually. Is delayed_y = medium and delayed_delayed_y = slow?

Comment: @AhmetBatuOrhan Yes. `delayed_y` is 1/2 the frequency of clock and `delayed_delayed_y` is 1/2 the frequency of `delayed_y`=>1/4 the frequency of `clock`

Comment: The logic to assign `delayed_y` and `delay_delayed_y` you wrote are inferred latches with asynchronous feedback. Simulation and synthesis will not match. They should be flopped with `posedge`. Preferably both should be flopped with `@(posedge clock)` to reduce the phase offset of the outputted clock edge

Comment: @Greg Yes you are right. I didn't realize this initially. I modified the code to flop `delayed_y` and `delayed_delayed_y` at `posedge clock`. I also decided to use a counter to slow down the clock. Any further improvements/suggestions are welcome.